# Why does the site icon have an L?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The title of the question says it all: wondering why the icon has an L, instead of an I? Is this a mistake by SE's designers, or is there a reason behind it?

It confused me quite a bit, as I don't know much about Iota, and so until I spotted the URL of the site I thought it must be Lota with a lowercase L!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not an 'L' — it's the [Greek lower-case iota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iota):

[image: Greek letter iota]   [image: Site logo]

<sup>Greek letter Iota        Iota site logo</sup>

The reason for choosing the symbol should now be a little more obvious, given the site's name of *Iota*. While many Stack Exchange sites are named after products with more official logos (such as [Iota's logo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOTA_(technology)#/media/File:Iota_logo.png)), the official logos are often not used — presumably, trademark licensing is a large factor here.

Comment: Thanks! I was shown an excerpt from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iota) which said "uppercase Ι, lowercase ι", but visiting it now I see the image you added above.

Comment: And actually putting ι in code blocks gives `ι` - guess it's a font thing

Comment: Indeed, [Salesforce site had to change their logo](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2047) to be different from the original one.